# Apple messages auto-call

Tags: ios, iphone

have an interesting problem I need to solve, I was hoping if anyone could give me some sort of an idea.

For example, if I get a text from someone saying (string) “URGENT” on my iPhone, I want to call them immediately.

So say I get a message, it could be any message but if their message says “urgent”, I need to call them ASAP, even when my phone is turned off.

Is there a way to do this, using API or anything?? I have no idea!!

Example say I get a messages saying:

Number 042XXXXX sends me a text:

"Hi Name, I have some urgent work for you"

Number 1300 XXX XXX sends me a text:
"Urgent help needed"

Both of these messages would be read by iPhone and their respective numbers would be dialled urgently.

Is there such a way to do this/automate this??

Any advice would be appreciated!!

I have no idea what to do, I am blank!!

Comment: No. You can't do this. Apps can't access message contents or sending numbers.

Comment: You can use the shortcuts app on your phone to trigger some action when a message is received containing "urgent" but you can't have the phone call a number in response; and you probably wouldn't want to. You need to be aware the phone is making a call otherwise how will you know to talk to the person?

Comment: Yeah because most likely it’s for my family members job that comes “first call first in” basis. So if he call that number he will get the job if he is first one to call it (he works as a tradesman)It’s a weird question I know but I would love to do this somehow. I tried shortcuts app. Is that anything else I can do then? Like if message that says “urgent” is received, my phone makes a sound??

Comment: If a special sound is sufficient for your purposes then you could get the iPhone owner to setup a second phone number on the phone, https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/iphone/iph9c5776d3c/ios and then set the ring tone for that number to be a different sound.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you have needs an indirect solution because, as Paulw11 points out, Apple don't allow you to inspect the message directly.

It would be possible to make use of Twilio's [Programmable SMS API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms) to setup a special phone number that customers could send text messages to.  Then you use the APIs of Twilio to read the messages and then send an Apple Push Notification message for those the had "urgent" in the message.

You could then write an iOS app which receives push notification messages and takes the actions you desire.  For example, it could present a screen which could automatically dial the number in question.

Comment: Would that be quick though? As we are waiting for the push notification, then we would need to call that number ASAP? Or would this be a fast solution? Like say I get a message that says “urgent” I want to call them in 30 seconds max

Comment: The API does not come will official timelines guarantees.  But in reality, it is a great API for timely delivery of message.  It is used in the banking world, for example, which has hard time limits.  You would get the push notification within a minute, often a few seconds.  There are edge cases but they are quite special conditions.